# Mail 365 rest api send message from java error

Tags: java, rest, office365

I am trying to send a message using java httpClient v4.4
I use as example the message you have provided.[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#MessageoperationsSendmessages)

I constantly get this error:
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidRequest","message":"Cannot read the request body."}}

This is my code.

```
String message = "{\"Message\":{\"Subject\":\"Meet for lunch?\",\"Body\":{\"ContentType\":\"Text\",\"Content\":\"The new cafeteria is open.\"},\"ToRecipients\":[{\"EmailAddress\":{\"Address\":\"my@mailadress.com\"}}],\"SaveToSentItems\":\"true\"}}";
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail");
    post.setHeader("authorization" ,"Bearer "+accessToken);
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("contnet-type", "application/json");
    post.setEntity(stringEntity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
    InputStream  in=null;
    BufferedReader buffer=null;


        String microsoftResponse = "";
        //System.out.println(response.toString());
        in= response.getEntity().getContent();
buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String s = "";
          while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            microsoftResponse += s;
          }
          System.out.println(microsoftResponse);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?? Can anybody suggest something please??

Comment: Check the JSON for errors; The content-type header is spelled wrong; and also check the rest url (the message id path param is missing)

Comment: I corrected the header.Problem persists.  Do I need a message_id to send an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL is `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail` is correct. Headers and Http Method also.

But the payload is in a wrong format (something went wrong with the nesting of the elements) - that is why the service responds with `Cannot read the request body.`.

The correct message payload would be

```
{
    "Message": {
        "Body": {
            "Content": "The new cafeteria is open.",
            "ContentType": "Text"
        },
        "Subject": "Meet for lunch?",
        "ToRecipients": [
            {
                "EmailAddress": {
                    "Address": "my@mailadress.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "SaveToSentItems": "true"
}
```

or ready to use in your Java code (properly escaped):

```
String message = "{\n" +
            "\"Message\": {\n" +
            "        \"Body\": {\n" +
            "            \"Content\": \"The new cafeteria is open.\",\n" +
            "            \"ContentType\": \"Text\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"Subject\": \"Meet for lunch?\",\n" +
            "        \"ToRecipients\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"EmailAddress\": {\n" +
            "                    \"Address\": \"my@mailadress.com\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"SaveToSentItems\": \"true\"\n" +
            "}";
```

I would strongly encourage you to use a library for converting POJOs into its JSONrepresentation. Have a look at [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works!!! Before I use Gson or Jackson I wanted  to send something simple. Your escaping saved my Day. Thank you again so much fateddy!!!